# python + worlds_simplist_web_browser + socket.error: [Errno 128] Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: python-2.7

I am following this course [here](http://www.pythonlearn.com/#) and the book [here](http://do1.dr-chuck.net/py4inf/EN-us/book.pdf).
I am having trouble getting the worlds_simplist_web_browser to work, chapt12 pg 144.
Can anyone advise what is wrong with my code. I am currently getting `socket.error: [Errno 128] Transport endpoint is not connected`. Or is it a network issue? I am currently in work. I can get curl and wget to work, so not sure what else to check.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.5

$ cat worlds_simplist_web_browser.py
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')

while True:
        data = mysock.recv(512)
        if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
                break
        print data

mysock.close()


$ python worlds_simplist_web_browser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "worlds_simplist_web_browser.py", line 5, in <module>
    mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')
socket.error: [Errno 128] Transport endpoint is not connected


$ ls
test  worlds_simplist_web_browser.py


$ wget http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt
--2017-01-11 09:51:37--  http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:53128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 167 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘romeo.txt’

100%[======================================>] 167         --.-K/s   in 0s

2017-01-11 09:51:37 (5.87 MB/s) - ‘romeo.txt’ saved [167/167]



$ curl http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

---

### EDIT1

I tried this in a different environment, but can't get it to work. 
I can get curl and wget to work.
Next for me is to try it at home.

```
root@e072d2cc7f74:/usr/share/nginx/html/python/chapt12# python worlds_simplist_web_browser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "worlds_simplist_web_browser.py", line 4, in <module>
    mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

root@e072d2cc7f74:/usr/share/nginx/html/python/chapt12# sudo python worlds_simplist_web_browser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "worlds_simplist_web_browser.py", line 4, in <module>
    mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out


root@e072d2cc7f74:/usr/share/nginx/html/python/chapt12# sudo -i
root@e072d2cc7f74:~#
root@e072d2cc7f74:~# python /usr/share/nginx/html/python/chapt12/worlds_simplist_web_browser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/nginx/html/python/chapt12/worlds_simplist_web_browser.py", line 4, in <module>
    mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
root@e072d2cc7f74:~#
```

---

### EDIT2

Think it might be the firewall at work, not sure.
Anyway got it to work by hosting my file `romeo.txt` on a server inside the firewall, so I don't have to go through the firewall.

```
$ cat local_worlds_simplist_web_browser.py
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('172.21.200.37', 80))
mysock.send('GET http://172.21.200.37/~dir_name/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')  # works
#mysock.send("GET /~dir_name/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n Host:http://172.21.200.37/\n\n") # works also other format to above

while True:
        data = mysock.recv(512)
        if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
                break
        print data

mysock.close()

$ python local_worlds_simplist_web_browser.py
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Jan 2017 20:16:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Jan 2017 20:03:20 GMT
ETag: "3215b4-a7-545d717aa5cf7"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 167
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

Comment: Did you try running it as `root`?

Comment: tks, i am using cygwin on windows. so not sure that applies? but i might be able to use docker to give me a more linex environment.

Comment: tried that, see my edit1 above. ideas greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The hostname does not go in the GET request - it's actually a separate header field.  Try:

`"GET /code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: http://www.py4inf.com\r\n\r\n"`

(Also note that line breaks in the header are properly CRLF, not just LF, but I think you can usually get away with that.)

Comment: tks but that did not work, same error `socket.error: [Errno 128] Transport endpoint is not connected`

Comment: tks this format works but that was not the issue, i think it migh be a firewall at work, so I put the file on server I have access to and tried that and it worked. will add and EDIT2 to my Q.